# Merging two XML files while transforming them using XSL

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have two XML files which I want to transform into one HTML file using XSL.

I transform them using `xsltproc first.xml transform.xsl > output.html` command in Linux terminal. Values from `first.xml` work perfectly and transform into HTML but I cannot force `second.xml` to work as well. It just didn't appear in file. I know there were questions like this on StackOverflow but I still couldn't figure out what I am doing wrong. It seems like something is wrong with `match = "document('effects.xml')/effects"` but I don't know what exactly.

**first.xml**

```
<elements>
  <listOfElements>
    <element>
      *some data*
    </element>
    <element>
      *some data*
    </element>
   </listOfElements>
</elements>
```

**second.xml**

```
<effects>
  <effect>
    <name> NAME1 </name>
    <cost> COST1 </cost>
  </effect>
  <effect>
    <name> NAME2 </name>
    <cost> COST2 </cost>
  </effect>
  <effect>
    <name> NAME3 </name>
    <cost> COST3 </cost>
  </effect>
</effect>
```

**transform.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;</xsl:text>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styl.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="elements"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="effects"/>
  </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="elements">
 <div>
  THIS WORKS
 </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="document('effects.xml')/effects">
<div>
  <xsl:for-each select="effects/effect">
    <div>
      <p><xsl:value-of select="name"/></p>
    </div>
  </xsl:for-each>
</div>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<xsl:apply-templates select="document('effects.xml')/effects"/>` and then in the `match="effects"` and `<xsl:for-each select="effect">`.